# reinitializing JQuery multiselect dropdown during ajax call does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, menu

I read some other posts where people lost their functionality of the dropdown after data was loaded with an ajax request.

None of those posts answered the question how to initialize a dropdown DURING the ajax call and not by success!

**Why would I need that?**
If a user selects a configuration from the drop-down menu to select specific data which is then loaded by clicking some button he might recognize that he forgot to select an option which he wanted to select. In this case, it should be possible to use the dropdown, to select the missing option and then start a new request (assuming that technical details like preventing multiple requests are handlet already).

I tried

```
loader = $.ajax({ stuff ....});
$('#someId').multiselect({
            name : 'someName',
            columns : 1,
            placeholder : 'Select something',
            selectAll : true
});
```

without a document.ready...
But additionally, I have a document.ready which handles the normal initialization.

How can the user still use the multiselect dropdown while the ajax call is going on?

**Why is it so important?**
Because some of the dropdown configurations load a lot of data from a db at a time (please no improvement suggestments for that - there are reasons for that!) and it would be nice not to be forced to wait till one request is done to be able to select a different dropdown configuration!

**EDIT:**
Of course, I could add another button that just stops the request and then one could select a new config and send a new request. 
Or using the same button for Start/Stop...but it seems not so elegant to me.

Comment: I am not familiar with JQuery multiselect (maybe you could tag the question with it, to help ppl find and understand).  How is functionality lost during an AJAX call, I mean what happens?  Are the errors?  Can you link to other questions where the same problem happens?

Comment: other questions where more about that the functionality was lost even after the call that is not the case!
i think it is not a specific jquery problem, it is more a conceptual thing if this is possible in the first place outside a document.ready function